# GET Request from Angular 1.5 to External Server

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, http-get

How do I make a GET request using Angular 1.5 to an external server that I do not have control over? I am receiving the error

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I cannot modify the server and therefore cannot add the resource. I have searched far and wide for a solution and cannot get the error to go away.

Comment: Try running it from IE/Firefox. In chrome use this extension : [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Comment: Search the internet about "CORS" - you will find plenty of resources. The solution has to be implemented server-side, so it depends on the technology of the server.

Comment: Use [CORS Toggle](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh) on the Chrome Browser. Or use a [CORS Proxy](https://crossorigin.me/)